# Decoded bitmap images aren't set in the photoboxes correctly

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, integer

```
private void BTN_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string DBpath = @"Data Source=.\StudentDB.db;Version=3;";
            Bitmap[] PictureBoxesBitmaps = {FirstPictureBitmap, SecondPictureBitmap, ThirdPictureBitmap };
            using SQLiteConnection connection = new(DBpath);
            using SQLiteCommand cmd = new(DBpath, connection);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM PictureBoxes";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            foreach (Bitmap bitmap in PictureBoxesBitmaps)
            {
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new();
                bitmap?.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] BitmapByteArray = ms.ToArray();
                var PictureBox64 = Convert.ToBase64String(BitmapByteArray);
                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO PictureBoxes(Encoded) VALUES('" + PictureBox64 + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

I'm using this first code to encode three bitmap images into a base64 string, then I'm storing them in a SQLite database.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RefreshData();
            using SQLiteConnection PicCheckerConnection = new(DBpath);
            using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(DBpath, PicCheckerConnection);
            PicCheckerConnection.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM (PictureBoxes) Limit "+ i +"," + i;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                using (SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (read.Read())
                     {
                        string Base64Image = read.GetString(0);
                        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64Image);
                        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                        if (i == 1) { pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);}
                        if (i == 2) { pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);}
                        if (i == 3) { pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);}
                     }
                    read.Close(); 
                }
            }
```

Then I wrote this code where it selects all three base64 strings from the SQLite database, decodes them and puts them in their pictureboxes respectively, the first base64 string --> the first picture box, second base64 string --> second picture box, and third base64 string --> third picture box.

However, when the program decodes the base64 strings and applies the images to the pictureboxes, the order is messed up.
The second decoded image is set in the first picturebox, and the third decoded image is set in the second picturebox and the first decoded image is not set in any of the pictureboxes.

I have tried debugging and changing the value of i, but sadly they did not help.

Comment: Debug your code, inspect the value of `i`,

Comment: Records in a Database by definition are unordered. You need to add an Order By cllause if you want to control the order.

Comment: @TaW I have them ordered in an ascending order and the issue is still happening.

Comment: _I have them ordered in an ascending order_ Well, that is not what I see in the SQL you show. Note that the order in which you add records is basically meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column for sorting with images to the table to store them, and sort them with the order by clause.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by adding a column for sorting with images?

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/ First, learn about the order by clause. 
Then recreate the PictureBoxes table adding a column to use for order by. You'll probably be better off if you learn database basics before writing any programs.